# Unknown size of windows partition

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my SSD alongside Windows. But when I select alongside Windows I can only choose my hard drive. In the advanced partition manager I can see that Ubuntu can't see the used space on my windows partition of my SSD. Why is that? My hard drive is GPT and my SSD is MBR.

Furthermore, it seems to think my windows boot manager is on my hard drive? Is that the reason why?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Edit: I have now moved the boot manager over to Windows.
Edit 2: For other users, moving the boot manager fixed this issue and I can now install Ubuntu to my SSD.

Comment: I think the reason if the fact that _partition_ is referred to as a dynamic partition on windows and Ubuntu can't read them unless changed to basic partition type.

Comment: See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363785(v=vs.85).aspx#dynamic_disks) for more information. You can't format such _disks_.